# Development Language IT on Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, region

Hello everyone I wanted to have information ...
I changed the development language on Xcode **EN -> IT**
Now I wanted to know if these changes will remain even when I publish the app on the app store or if they remain only during development

[image]

My app is for Italy only and I wanted to know if I can avoid entering `Locale(identifier: "it")` for each date display, now that I have set the development language to **Italian**.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to go to `File > New File > Strings File`, name it `Localizable.strings`, this is important.
Open the attribute inspector. Click `Localize...`, select your language.

In your file, for each piece of text you want to show in your app, come up with an identifier/key for it, then write as follows:

```swift
"welcome_message" = "Welcome to my app!"; // This would be in your English file.
```

Then do the same thing for each language you want to support, but just change the phrase itself in each file, and keep the same key/identifier.
Then when you want to use that phrase in your app, replace whichever String with `NSLocalizedString("welcome_message", comment: "")`

No need to set `Locale(identifier:String)` in your files. The app will look for the device's set language and use the corresponding Localizable.strings file.

Comment: obligatorily insert a localizable file string even if my app must contain only texts in Italian? I have no other languages ​​to show

Comment: Then why don't you just write your strings in their respective parts of your code in Italian? I'm not understanding your issue. Localization is only needed for using multiple languages. If you want to support English and Italian, do it my way. If you want only Italian, then it doesn't matter what language the device is set to or what your project is set to or anything. Just state in App Store Connect that you're using Italian.

Comment: I created my question because when I work with Date I always get the format in English and I wanted to avoid specifying the Italian Locale identifier every time I use Date ... that's why I asked my question

Comment: Hmm I don't know then. Maybe some global property similar to `UITableView.appearance()` where you can specify attributes in your AppDelegate and then they will take effect in any instance of a UITableView unless you override them.